# How can I monitor all SQL commands that go through a ODBC User DSN

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access, odbc, dsn

How can I monitor all SQL commands that go through a ODBC User DSN?

the datasource is using the SQL Server native Client 10.0 driver.

I have an access app with hundreds of confusingly complex reports.  Over the last 3 years We have ported the app to ColdFusion and MS Sql server and one of the reports has some inconsistencies with the access version of the app.

I've tried tracing the code through in the access app to discern exactly what is going on but I've been unable to figure it out.  The access app uses an ODBC user DSN with the SQL Server native Client 10.0 driver. Is there some way I can monitor the datasource and see all the sql commands that are executed over that channel?

Comment: On the client side, you can use the [Windows ODBC Data Source Administrator to set up tracing](http://www.easysoft.com/support/kb/kb00946.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setup a SQL Server profile trace and capture the command being executed on the server. I assume you are using MSSQL as the backend?

Answer (score 0):

https://expressprofiler.codeplex.com

It's free profiler in case you use SQL Server Express version.